# How to use create tags Python Azure SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to create tags in Azure 2.0.0rc2 using Python.
Following is the code i used:

```
def __update_tags(self):
    username = 'user@xyz.com'
    password = 'user@1234'
    subscription_id = '478-ytehn-47ds5-784aa-4758a'
    credentials = UserPassCredentials(username=username, password=password)
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials=credentials)
    tag_operations = TagOperations(client=resource_client)
    tag_operations.create_or_update_value(tag_name='key_1', tag_value='val_1')
```

On running this code i am getting error like:

```
    if self.client.credentials.subscription_id is not None:
AttributeError: 'UserPassCredentials' object has no attribute 'subscription_id'
```

Anyone have idea to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, subscription_id is specified but not used. You need the subscription_id when creating the resource_client. Please replace "**resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials=credentials)"** with the code below:

```
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
ResourceManagementClientConfiguration(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)
```

Check [here](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagement.html#create-the-management-client) for more information.

Update:
confirm import ResourceManagementClientConfiguration
[image]

Comment: i have tried this way but in azure 2.0.0rc2 `from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import  ResourceManagementClientConfiguration
` is not available. Can you please verify once.

Comment: @ramkumar what do you mean not available? I can confirm from my side that **from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClientConfiguration**  definitely works. Check the updates in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documents ([Resource Management](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagement.html) and [Resource Management Authentication](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagementauthentication.html)), as @forester123 said, summarize the code as below.

```
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient, ResourceManagementClientConfiguration

username = 'user@xyz.com'
password = 'user@1234'
subscription_id = '478-ytehn-47ds5-784aa-4758a'

credentials = UserPassCredentials(username, password)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    ResourceManagementClientConfiguration(
        credentials,
        subscription_id
    )
)
```